# Is Java Servlet Container also a class?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, containers

Is the container a set of environment or just a Java class that can call methods in servlets?
What's the component of servlets container?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet Container is a java application (Multiple java classes with a Main class), this application implement the Java Servlet Specifications: https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr369/index.html

Answer (score 0):

No, a servlet container is a server, for example, Tomcat, Jetty, Glassfish and so on.
They manage user's session and create threads, receive data via sockets, and parse a request. In the end, a servlet container triggers an appropriate method of the servlet class according to the xml servlet config.

p.s. I wrote so simple steps of servlet container flow.
If you are interested in, you should find more articles about this, but I suggest you read the documentation of some server, which you chose.